# Unable to use @Entity ,@Id annotations in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am a newbie in using google loud endpoints in m android app.

I followed several tutorials on developing a GAE back-end for my android app in android studio.
I made an android app and then auto-generated back-end for it.

In back-end module I created a bean and auto-generated end point class for it. But when I try to add annotations like @Entity,@Id etc then they are not recogniZed.
I have added objectify-4.0b1 jar to WEB-INF/lib in api project.

What am I missing?
Please advise.

Manish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE needs to know about the objectify library. Did you use the Google Cloud Module generation built into Android Studio to create your endpoint?  If so you should have your backend configured through Gradle.  This would give you two options:
option 1) is add the following line to your dependencies clause in your backend build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:4.0b1'
```

Although the latest version is 5.1.4 so if you can you should just use that.

option 2) is to go to file -> project structure, then select your backend module and add a library dependency. That will popup a search dialog where you can search for the objectify dependency and automatically add it to your module. This will update your build.gradle for you.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.I made the changes and all is fine now.